# Extra Paragraph Character After Header and Footer from Quick Part Gallery

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office

If I insert a header or footer from the quick part gallery, it usually adds a standalone paragraph character on the next line.

This is extremely annoying because it requires cleanup every time. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? A couple of the default headers from the quick parts gallery do not do this. The ones I've created myself do - for both header and footer -even when I've explicitly removed this when it's auto-generated and resaved the part.

I've currently got a VBA macro that adds all these headers and footers automatically to documents in a directory, but it doesn't do me much good when I have to go in and hit delete twice for every document anyway. I can find and replace the paragraph markers (^p^p) through the script (which only works in the header), but doing so strips the style from the header. I'd rather these just not be a part of the quick part if that's an option. They weren't there when I saved the part out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I understand your frustration.*

> If I insert a header or footer from the quick part gallery, it usually adds a standalone paragraph.

### The built-in building block headers are not all the same.

**Some have that paragraph mark and some do not.** I have taken at least one that does have the mark, the one shown in [your Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956178/extra-paragraph-character-after-header-and-footer-from-quick-part-gallery), which is titled misleadingly "Blank Header," and recreated it without the paragraph mark.

When inserted manually, the original adds the paragraph mark.

[image: screenshot header with extra mark]

My recreated one does not.

When you create your own, place a space after your content, then select everything but the space when you create the building block.

Here I followed those directions with the Blank Header and recreated it with the name _Blank.

[image: Create new Building Block dialog]

[image: Insert Header drop down]

*(After I created the BB but before the screenshot above, I changed the category from "General" to "Built-In" so they would both appear in the same menu location.)*

When inserted using Insert Header it is inserted without the extra paragraph mark.

[image: screenshot header]

Here is a [temporary link to a template with the header building block](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhsuldqohvrktry/blank%20header%20holder.dotx?dl=0) that I created.

I am confident that if you do the same with your custom header and footer building blocks, you will no longer have the extra paragraph mark. This is true whether you use the Insert > Header, Insert > Footer, and Insert Page Number manual methods or use vba.

**Note:** there is a bug when *pasting content* into a header or footer to completely replace the default paragraph mark. When that is done, you *do* end up with an extra paragraph mark. This is in Edit Header or Edit Footer view.

### Sharing and Inserting Building Block Using vba

1. Create your building blocks in a separate template. If you are using them only with a particular document template, they can be stored in that template. If you are using them for multiple documents, they should be in a [global template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global). Here is my writing on [where building blocks can be stored](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks).
2. For sharing, the template should be either a shared global template or in the shared Workgroup Templates folder if a document template.
3. Since the menu versions of Word, vba for insertion of building blocks has gotten more complex. Here is [my writing on that with code samples](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock). The exact code depends on the location of the building block and its relation to the template holding the code. I have given specific code in response to [your question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956178/extra-paragraph-character-after-header-and-footer-from-quick-part-gallery/67964121#67964121).

Comment: I think the piece I was missing was to add a space after the content before I highlight the part and save it out. I usually just use Ctrl+A, then Save. It's probably picking up a hidden formatting character when I do that. Trying this now. THANK YOU for all the time you put into answering both ends of the question in both forums.

Comment: This worked - perfectly. THank you.

Comment: Oddly enough - this worked, until I ran the script - it seems like the script somehow modifies the building block. After I run the script, even inserting the parts manually adds the extra line.

Comment: I wonder if it's because the part was added to the attachedtemplate of the documents - so when I modified normal, it didn't matter, it still pulls instead from the attached template, which has the wrong version of the building block... I'll use a different name to test. It could also be because I run multiple operations on the selection, which also tends to add paragraphs.

Comment: The normal template is generally one of the worst locations to save building blocks. See the code in the vba question which can be used to distinguish the source. Usually the best source for the building block is the same template holding the code, in which case you can use ThisDocument. --- Try learning to use the Range rather than the Selection. It makes code much faster.  Here is my writing on what happens when multiple building blocks have the same name: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#same_name.

Answer (score 0):

When you select your footer content to save it to the Footer Gallery (as a Building Block/Quick Part), make sure that the paragraph mark (¶) is **not** selected (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> if needed to make paragraph marks visible). Note that I don't mean the ¶ at the end of the extra line that you're getting, but the one at the end of the actual line that you want to appear in the footer. Also, in the **Create New Building Block** dialog box where you enter the properties for the new footer, make sure that the **Options** field is set to **Insert content only** (though that should be the default value for footers).

Comment: I don't believe it allows me to save the part if I don't highlight that - or at least, it wouldn't allow me NOT to select that; I think the space that Charles alluded to is for this reason. In any case, once I deselect that character (after adding a space between it and the marker) - it does the job. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Eakins. Strange. It works for me (and has worked for me for years).